# how to create xcframework from swift package which has binaryTarget

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am a new developer for iOS. I have a swift package with three modules (A, B, C). A is the product Module A is written in Swift, module B is in objective C, module C is binary target. B is A's dependency, C is B's dependency. How to create xcframework to release as SDK for this swift package? Thanks a lot.

Here is the package.swift:

let package = Package( name: "A", platforms: [.iOS(.v14), .macOS(.v11)], products: [ .library( name: "A", targets: ["A"] ) ], dependencies: [ // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"), ], targets: [ .target( name: "A", dependencies: ["B"] ), .target( name: "B", dependencies: ["C"], publicHeadersPath: "include" ), .binaryTarget( name: "c", url: "url", checksum: "checksum" ), .testTarget( name: "ATests", dependencies: ["A"] ) ], cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx11

If someone can provide instruction steps by steps, or provide some documents.